# Where is GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV defined?

Tags: c++, opengl

I can't seem to find where `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV` is defined. Googling around, I only seem to find places where it had been defined manually:

```
#define GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV 0x8367
```

It doesn't appear to be in `gl/GL.h` or `gl/GLU.h` or even anywhere in `Windows.h`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows ships with an outdated version of `<gl/GL.h>` (the Windows version of this file was obsolete back in 1998, as of 2013 it still hasn't been updated).  You will need to use something like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) to get access to modern OpenGL features on Windows.  This will provide a complete OpenGL header, as well as a library to automatically detect OpenGL extensions.

Comment: Does that imply that `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV` would raise the required OpenGL version requirements? Presently my code only requires like `OpenGL 1.2`.

Comment: You can also download [GL/glext.h](http://www.opengl.org/registry/) from the OpenGL site which has it.

Comment: @Mr.Smith: Microsoft's version of OpenGL is actually 1.1.  `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV` is part of the OpenGL 1.2 standard, it was promoted from `EXT_packed_pixels`.

Comment: @Mr.Smith Out of curiosity, why do you write an OpenGL 1.2 application these days? There are many advantages of using modern OpenGL.